# Retrieve DNA sequence using a gene identifier of a protein

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, ncbi

Im using Biopython to try to retrieve the DNA sequence corresponding to protein of which I have a GI(71743840), from the NCBI page this is very easy, I just need to look for the refseq. My problem comes when coding it in python, using ncbi fetch utilities, I can't find a way to retrieve any field that would help me to go to DNA.

```
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=blast_record.alignments[0].hit_id, rettype="gb", retmode="text")
seq_record=SeqIO.read(handle,"gb")
```

There is a lot of information in seq_record.features, but there must be an easier and obvious way to do this, any help would be appreciated.
Thnx!

Comment: what is the value of `blast_record.alignments[0].hit_id`

Comment: ah, sorry for that, in this case, it is jsut the GI of the protein "71743840"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to access the annotations of the SeqRecord:

```
seq_record=SeqIO.read(handle,"gb")
nucleotide_accession = seq_record.annotations["db_source"]
```

In your case `nucleotide_accession` is "REFSEQ: accession NM_000673.4"

Now look if you can parse those annotations. With only this test case:

```
nucl_id = nucleotide_accession.split()[-1]

handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide",
                       id=nucl_id,
                       rettype="gb",
                       retmode="text")
seq_record = SeqIO.read(handle, "gb")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take advantage of the Entrez.elink, request the UID of the protein sequence corresponding to the UID of the nucleotide sequence:

```
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import SeqIO
email = 'seb@free.fr'
term = 'NM_207618.2' #fro example, accession/version

### first step, we search for the nucleotide sequence of interest
h_search = Entrez.esearch(
        db='nucleotide', email=email, term=term)
record = Entrez.read(h_search)
h_search.close()

### second step, we fetch the UID of that nt sequence
handle_nt = Entrez.efetch(
        db='nucleotide', email=email, 
        id=record['IdList'][0], rettype='fasta') # here is the UID

### third and most important, we 'link' the UID of the nucleotide
# sequence to the corresponding protein from the appropriate database
results = Entrez.read(Entrez.elink(
        dbfrom='nucleotide', linkname='nucleotide_protein',
        email=email, id=record['IdList'][0]))

### last, we fetch the amino acid sequence
handle_aa = Entrez.efetch(
        db='protein', email=email, 
        id=results[0]['LinkSetDb'][0]['Link'][0]['Id'], # here is the key...
        rettype='fasta')
```